# Keep session active when calling wcf REST from asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

I have a WCF Rest Service, and I am trying to call this from an aspx page on the same website (i.e. both rest and website are on the same website) . I need to keep the session active. the following is happening 
 If I do not pass the session cookie, The service creates a different session. If I pass the Session cookie, the httpwebrequest takes a long time and then gives a timeout. 
 Is there something I am doing wrong? Or Perhaps there is a better way to call a REST service whilst keeping the same session of the calling asp.net page.

I have the following Rest Signature:

```
        [OperationContract()]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetFilterQuery(LookupRequestDTO request);
```

From code-behind I am calling this service as follows:

```
  HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url)
                                 as HttpWebRequest;

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        string result = null;
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        req.Referer = this.Page.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();//pass session state;    
        cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie() { Domain = req.RequestUri.Host, Name = "ASP.NET_SessionId", Value = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID });

        req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

        string data = null; 
        //code that populates data goes here ... (excluded for simplification)

        using (Stream webStream = req.GetRequestStream())
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            requestWriter.Write(data);
        }


   using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()  //timeout occurs here
                                  as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        StreamReader reader =
            new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

    }
```

the service works correctly and keeps same session when called from javascript using $.ajax approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some more reseach on this and the best approach was to re-design the architecture.
Basically, it dod not make much sense to call REST from code-behid. It is simply not the right tool.
Rather than creating a wcf service, I am calling the actual code.
However the code is not being called directly, I am using the Command Pattern. this is to keep separation of concern (without performance bottleneck of wcf communication).

If anyong has a solution for the timeout issue, please let me know. For now, I will mark this as answered.